# How to set dynamic cell separation line in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a tableView in this tableview data comes dynamically . I want to show only data available cell separation line not in hole tableview separation line like below image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

in case when your array count(table datasource) in less then 6.
you need to make table height dynamic.. by calculating (array count) * row height(44). .

if your array count is greater then 6 then you doesn't need to do anything

Answer (score 0):

Set **TableView Separator None**

Then, Create a custom TableViewCell, needed  views and at the bottom add a label like a line,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you want, but is seems to me that solution would be to either set the table view style to *Grouped* or override *tableView: viewForFooterInSection:* method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}
```